# What does this error message mean: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'TEMPFILE'

Tags: visual-studio, linker, vcbuild

I'm building a C program with Visual Studio 2008, from the command line.

```
vcbuild /logcommands foo.vcproj
```

From the GUI, the build works fine. But from the command line, the build fails at the link stage, with these error mesages:

```
Linking...
   Creating library c:\foo\out\foo.lib and object c:\foo\out\foo.exp
Generating code
Finished generating code
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'TEMPFILE'
Build log was saved at "file://c:\foo\out\BuildLog.htm"
```

What's this `TEMPFILE`, and how do I fix the build?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linker is trying to create a temporary file in the directory indicated by the `TMP` environment variable. Make sure that `TMP` is set and that it points to a directory where the linker can create files and that has enough disk space. E.g.,

```
set TMP=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Local Settings\Temp
vcbuild /logcommands foo.vcproj
```

*(Found in the [SCons FAQ](http://www.scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Linking_on_Windows_gives_me_an_error%3a_LINK%3a_fatal_error_LNK1104%3a_cannot_open_file_.27TEMPFILE.27._How_do_I_fix_this.3F) of all places. My build scripts were messing up with `TMP` before calling `vcbuild`, for some unfathomable reason.)*